# Exporting session.cookies as JSON

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, python-requests

I am writing a script that interacts with a website using requests - at some point the cookies need to transferred into selenium as a part of the work needs to be done on a webdriver.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import cfscrape
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

scraper = cfscrape.create_scraper()


headers = {'Referer': 'https://www.off---white.com/en/GB/login'}
payload = {
    'utf8':'✓',
    'authenticity_token':'',
    'spree_user[email]': LOGIN_EMAIL,
    'spree_user[password]': PASSWORD,
    'spree_user[remember_me]': '0',
    'commit': 'Login'
}
r = scraper.post('https://www.off---white.com/en/GB/login', data=payload, headers=headers)
if r.status_code != 200:
    print('Failed to log in')
else:
    print('Successfully logged in!')

cookiesexport = scraper.cookies

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.off---white.com/en/GB")
time.sleep(10)
driver.add_cookie(cookiesexport)
time.sleep(2)
driver.get("https://www.off---white.com/en/GB/checkout/payment")
```

When I run the code above I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Object of type 'RequestsCookieJar' is not JSON serializable
```

I presume this is due to scraper.cookies not being in JSON format.

My question is how do I export the cookies in JSON format?

Comment: try to replace `driver.add_cookie(cookiesexport)` with `driver.add_cookie(cookiesexport.get_dict())`

Comment: @EugeneK I have tried the above and it returns the following error - selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: invalid argument: missing 'name'

Comment: according to the [documentation](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.add_cookie) `add_cookie` accepts specific format.
could you `print(cookiesexport.get_dict())` and check if there is a format that `add_cookie` expects?

Comment: Also, keep in mind that `add_cookie` accept one cookie at a time, so if you have many you should add them one by one.

Comment: @EugeneK I have to my cookieexport to print the following {'_hs_session_v3': 'RANDOM_STRING'}. When I try to add this cookie to selenium I get the following. 
    selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: invalid argument: missing 'name'

Comment: your cookie must have `'name'` and `'value'` keys, you should change your cookie to be like this `{'name': '_hs_session_v3', 'value': 'RANDOM_STRING'}`

Comment: @EugeneK Thank you so much! When doing this manually it worked. How would I go about converting the format?

Comment: please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

To convert `cookies` from `scraper`:

```
cookies = [{'name': key, 'value': value} for key, value in cookiesexport.iteritems()}]
for cookie in cookies:
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
```